# HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-s3, wget, http-status-code-403

Using `wget` to get a file from S3 via a `presignedUrl`, I can get the file in my local PC using

```
wget 'https:xxxxx' -O theFile
```

but when I tried to get the file in a remote (out of my control), It prompted me of this error:

```
Connecting to xxxx.s3-xxx.amazonaws.com (xxxx.s3-xxx.amazonaws.com)|52.219.68.171|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2018-09-12 09:50:57 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

#### Update 2018-09-13

Not only the `presignedUrl`, actually I cannot download it via `aws s3 cp` with credentials as

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AAA AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=BBB aws s3 cp hello.sh.yml s3://opt-prometheus-rules-test/ # to upload

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AAA AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=BBB aws s3 cp s3://opt-prometheus-rules-test/JmeterTest.jmx . # to download
```

In the end, it turned out that the problem lies in the `access policy` which is set wrongly to prohibited all the **getting** operations.

I contacted the administrator to solve the problem by modifying the access policy.

Answer (score 0):

If your doubt on this error related to AWS S3 website hosting over linux server then continue reading.

Go to the AWS services S3 and click your created bucket and then click PERMISSIONS tab and the click EDIT option on the  right side and then give READ access for Everyone (public access)'s Objects and Object ACL.

Below to this give acknowledge to your access I understand the effects of these changes on this object.

Give save changes. now go back to command prompt and your error will disappear.